# Spring websocket(stomp, sockjs): Controller didn't get whole data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket, stomp

I'm changing my app using stomp and sockjs.

But somehow my controller can't get my whole data from client.

This is from my **client** side.

```
>>> SEND
destination:/app/hello
content-length:57

{"type":"greeting","user":"james","to":"","message":"hi"}�
```

with my **controller**

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
public void greeting(ChatMessage message, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) throws Exception{
    logger.debug(">>>[GREETING]\n{}", message.toString());

    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic", message);
}
```

**ChatMessage**

```
public class ChatMessage {
private String user;

private String to;

private String message;

private String type;

///

@Override
public String toString(){
    return String.format("ChatMessage [type=" + getType() + ", username="+ getUsername() +", to=" + getToUser() + ", message=" + getMessage() + "]");
}
```

}

My controller only get **message** and **type**

where is my **user**?

*`ChatMessage [type=greeting, username=, to=, message=hi]`*

Does anyone know what happens with my code?
Thx

Comment: mapping is incorrect. change your getter and setter for proper deserialization or use @JsonProperty on top of user field.  user field has getter as getUsername(). mismatch!

Answer (score 0):

End up I change my Model ChatMessage

```
public class ChatMessage {

private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> any(){
    return this.map;
}

public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
    return this.map;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setMap(String key, Object value) {
    map.put(key, value);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Map [map=" + map + "]";
}
}
```

So I could have the different type of message cause sometimes I want to send SDP message and offer description.